# MySQL - Bulk insertion into table from the result of a select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I want to grab all rows from table `items` where `id > 100`

```
SELECT `id` FROM `items` WHERE `id` > 100
```

And for each of these rows returned from above `select`, insert a new row into the `item_tags` table;

```
INSERT INTO `item_tags` (`item_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES (107, 123)
INSERT INTO `item_tags` (`item_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES (114, 123)
.
.
.
INSERT INTO `item_tags` (`item_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES (299, 123)
```

Can I do this in a single query in MySQL?

Comment: You can use INSERT ... SELECT... anda since MySql 8.0.19 You can use INSERT .. TABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `item_tags` (`item_id`, `tag_id`) 
SELECT `id`, 123 FROM `items` WHERE `id` > 100
```

This will insert one record in `item_tags` for each record in `items` having `id > 100`, with a fixed value of `123` for column `tag_id`.